# Why i get this error TypeError:'type' object is not iterable in Python Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

im getting this Error Then i run my Code

i have treid to make a class but nothing Works

```
import subprocess
import time
import pyautogui as pg
from robot.api import logger
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError, check_output
import weakref

    def close_application(self):
        """
        Closes a application prior opened by open_application.
        """
        logger.info("Closing application...")
        subprocess.Popen(self.sigmaProcess)
        self.sigmaProcess.communicate(self.sigmaProcess, timeout=None)
        self.sigmaProcess.kill()
        self.sigmaProcess.communicate(self.sigmaProcess)
```

The Main Code

```
def open_application(self, path, workingDir):
    """
    Opens a application.
    :param path: The application path.
    :param workingDir: The application's working dir.
    """
    logger.info("Opening {} with working directory {}...".format(path, workingDir))
    self.sigmaProcess = subprocess.Popen([path], cwd=workingDir)
```

here is subprocess.Popen defined

```
*** Settings ***
Resource                       ../sigma.robot
Suite Teardown  click on       processOverviewTab
*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    close application
    open application
    wait for on tab     processOverviewTab  600000
```

The Code for the Test

```
Test title :: Prüft den bug                                           Using centered capture region (570.0, 390.0, 800, 480).
| FAIL |
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

and this is the Error Message

and when i Delete th subprocess.Popen and self.sigmaProcess.communicate i get this Error 
AttributeError: type object 'Popen' has no attribute 'returncode'

Comment: can none Helps me?

Comment: we can't help unless you provide a bit more information. We need to know which line of which function is causing that error.

Comment: in The Main Code Close Application